# Output record without duplicate

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table like this and i want to output without duplication of the same user. If i use `group by` it shows only one record on the same column. iam also using left join for `location` and `user name`. A little help

```
+------+---------+----------+---------+
| user | work id | location |  time   |
+------+---------+----------+---------+
|    1 |      42 |        1 | 2hr     |
|    1 |      42 |        1 | 10min   |
|    1 |      42 |        1 | 30min   |
|    2 |      42 |        1 | 4hr     |
|    2 |      42 |        1 | 2.30min |
|    1 |      50 |        2 | 4min    |
|    1 |      50 |        2 | 5min    |
|    2 |      20 |        3 | 3hr     |
|    1 |      20 |        3 | 6hr     |
+------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Iam looking for this

```
+------+---------+----------+
| user | work id | location |
+------+---------+----------+
|    1 |      42 |        1 |
|    1 |      50 |        2 |
|    1 |      20 |        3 |
|    2 |      42 |        1 |
|    2 |      20 |        3 |
+------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: I think ```group by work_id``` should work.

Comment: Did you try ```DISTINCT``` keyword for unique data?

Comment: I just did ```select distinct user,workid,location from so order by 1``` and the result is your desired output, and i know I didn't join two tables. But this should be the way to go. Hope it helps!!

Comment: It looks like `work_id` and `location` are 1:1.  If so, why have both columns?

Comment: There are lot of different numbers further down. i just simplified the table here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need a distinct clause here -

```
SELECT DISTINCT user
               ,workid
               ,location
FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY user
        ,location
```

Comment: `distinct` removes duplicate records. So in my table it will remove the duplicate user and keep only one , because we are telling the query to look at the another table for comprision

Comment: @Dexter, I beg to differ. Distinct clause works at last of the query execution. Once query executed and fetches the whole records, distinct clause remove the duplicate records from the result set.

Comment: @Dexter, Selecting all unique {col1, col2, col3} means the same as i have said earlier.